# Datatables Not Merging VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, merge

I have some code that is intended to:

 1. Loop through a datagrid that is user populated 

 2. Search an access database using the input criteria 

 3. Return the results as a datatable 

 4. Merge additional results to that datatable 

 5. Bind the merged table results to a DataGridView

The query works, results return as expected with a single value search. The query will also return one of the two test values if I use the user input DataGridView. However, it will not combine the two results before outputting to the results_DataGridView. I have also tried using .Fill from the adapter to add onto my temp table and use that as the datasource.

---

```
    Option Strict On

Dim dt_TempTable As New DataTable
Dim dt_ContentsTable As New DataTable
Dim SerialNumbers As New List(Of String)
Dim PanelIDs As New List(Of String)
Dim MultiSearch As Boolean

Private Sub bgwk_data_DoWork(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles bgwk_data.DoWork

    If Not (MultiSearch) Then
        Retrieveinfo(Me.txt_SerialNumber.Text, Me.txt_PanelID.Text) 'Local
    Else
        Dim arrSN As String() = SerialNumbers.ToArray()
        Dim arrPID As String() = PanelIDs.ToArray()

        For i = 0 To arrSN.Count - 1

            If i > 0 Then

                Retrieveinfo(arrSN(i), arrPID(i)) 'Local - Run query and create a new temp table of results

                dt_ContentsTable.Merge(dt_TempTable) 'Merge new temp table to current contents table

            Else
                dt_ContentsTable = Retrieveinfo(arrSN(i), arrPID(i)) 'Return the original temp table to the contents table (datagridview datasource)
            End If
        Next
    End If

End Sub

'Gets the Data by SerialNumber and saves it to dt_TempTable to be bound afterwards
Private Function Retrieveinfo(SerialNumber As String, PanelID As String) As DataTable
    Dim ds As New datasource
    Dim tblAdapt As New datasourceTableAdapters.toHTML_SPC_DataTableAdapter

    tblAdapt.GetData(dt_TempTable, SerialNumber, PanelID)

    Return dt_TempTable 'Return the table
End Function

'Updates dg_data with the datatable from Retrieveinfo and refreshes the form
Private Sub bgwk_dataRunWorkerCompleted(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs) Handles bgwk_data.RunWorkerCompleted
    'Unlocks ability to search new things
    Me.txt_PanelID.ReadOnly = False
    Me.txt_SerialNumber.ReadOnly = False
    Me.dg_data.ReadOnly = False

    'Binds the backgroundworker results to the datagridview
    Me.dg_data.DataSource = Nothing
    Me.dg_data.DataSource = dt_ContentsTable

    Me.dg_data.Refresh()
    Me.Refresh()
End Sub
```

---

I understand that merge can be used on DataTables, but perhaps this is incorrect usage?

Comment: @AndrewMorton I am testing it out now. Side question: is it always recommended to use `Option Strict On`? Thanks

Comment: Yes, you should pretty much ALWAYS have `Option Strict On`. Set it `On` in your project properties and then set it `On` in the IDE options too, so it will be `On` by default for future projects. You should only turn it `Off` when you specifically need to for the purposes of late-binding. Even then, you should only turn it `Off` at the file level and only in code files containing partial classes with ONLY the bare minimum code that actually requires late-binding.

Comment: @AndrewMorton; Changing `Option Strict On` did not fix the issue.

Comment: @AndrewMorton; I also forgot to include the public variables I was using. Which probably did not help regarding the `Option Strict On` bit. I use public variables to manage the BackGroundWorker and avoid cross-thread issues. Might be horrendous misuse, but I am still learning.

Comment: Why the down vote?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd go with a condition in the multi-search loop:

```
If dt_ContentsTable.Rows.Count = 0 Then
    dt_ContentsTable = dt_TempTable.Clone()
End If
dt_ContentsTable.Merge(dt_TempTable)
```

This way, the first time, its at least creating the columns of the dt_ContentsTable.

I also don't see any code in the single search where dt_ContentsTable is assigned.  So, in the single search, I recommend you assign dt_ContentsTable to dt_TempTable.

Comment: You were right about the single search. I have adjusted it. Still working through this issue. No suggestions have worked yet, and now I am rebuilding my SQL statement to make sure that it really works as expected. I will continue to update this question as I discover any working solutions.

Comment: The first time in the loop...the dt contents needs columns added before the nerge occurs...cannot merge into a table with no columns...that is what clone should do